# Calling a sub with a parameter

Tags: excel, vba

A subroutine needs a variable that's been declared and initialised in an userform.

The problem: the `store_name` string variable is not declared. I must be doing something wrong with the scopes of the subs or with the syntax.

The entire program does the following: an userform takes the string inputed by the user, and the main sub concatenates it to every cell in a column.

This is the userform code:

```
Sub OKButton_Click(ByRef store_name As String)

    store_name = store.Text
    Unload Me
    inputStoreName store_name

End Sub
```

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim store_name As String
    UserForm2.OKButton_Click store_name

End Sub
```

This is the subroutine that uses the variable:

```
Sub inputStoreName(ByRef store_name As String)

    Dim store_range as Range
    Dim cell as Range
    ...
    for each cell in store_range 
        cell.value = store_name & cell.value
    Next cell

End Sub
```

And this is the main subroutine that should be run from the macro list:

```
Public Sub fixColumns()

    ...
    inputStoreName store_name 
    ...

End Sub
```

I need the main sub `fixColumns` to be called from the macro list, so I thought to create a separate sub `inputStoreName` that takes the userform variable, and call that function from the `fixColumns` sub.

This looks simple enough, but in `fixColumns` I get the error that the variable `store_name` is undefined.

Comment: Delete the line Dim store_name As String in the Sub CommandButton1_Click(), and declare in a module this> Public store_name As String ........... So can use it after unloding the form.

Comment: Do you use Option Explicit?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.